# How may some apps use another payment methods in Android although it's prohibited by google?

Tags: android, paypal, google-play, in-app-billing

I am confused about Developer Policy. As i read ([Developer Policy](https://play.google.com/intl/en-US/about/monetization-ads/index.html)) we have to use google in-app billing methods except:

> 1. Payment is solely for physical products
> 2. Payment is for digital content that may be consumed outside of the app itself (e.g. songs that can be played on other music players).

But for example Badoo uses different payment methods in app:

[image]

I think badoo doesn't meet the required specifications as described above. So, how they may use different payment methods?

In my Android app, users buy credits and they use this credits to ask questions to consultants. My problem is that google’s transaction fee is %30, this is so much for my app. Can i use Stripe in my app?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a question about Google Play Store policy.

Comment: @ianhanniballake where should i ask this question?

Comment: you should probably ask a lawyer as these would be legal questions.